# Best practice to detect if 2 customers try to use same credit card in braintree

Tags: braintree

I want to know what's the best practice if:

- User1 uses card xyz1 and xyz1 successfully verified and added in braintree.
- User2 uses same card xyz1 and xyz1 verification failed and added in braintree with verification failure reason.
- I want to find users which try xyz1 (either successful or failed) in braintree.

**Anything like fingerprint in stripe.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You can search for transactions in your vault that used the same credit card by [using the credit card unique identifier](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card#unique_number_identifier) in a [transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/search#credit_card_unique_identifier) search. This will get you a response containing all transactions that made use of the same card. From there, you can inspect the transaction response object for [information about the customer that created it](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction#customer_details.id).

You cannot use the credit card unique identifier in verification searches. Instead, you could search for verifications based on [customer ID](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/credit-card-verification/search#customer_id) or [payment method token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/credit-card-verification/search#payment_method_token), then [pull the credit card unique identifier from the verification response object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card-verification#credit_card.unique_number_identifier).

In Ruby, the transaction search would look something like this:

```
collection = Braintree::Transaction.search do |search|
  search.credit_card_unique_identifier.is "the_unique_identifier"
end

collection.each do |transaction|
  puts transaction.customer_details.id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an option in their PaymentMethod.create call that will fail if the same card has already been added to your Braintree Vault.  Link to that attribute [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/ruby#options.fail_on_duplicate_payment_method)